# bower ECMDERR fatal: dumb http transport does not support --depth

Tags: git, bower, bower-install

running bower install, I obtain the following error message:

```
...
bower require-handlebars-plugin#0.8.0         checkout v0.8.0
bower nouislider#master                       checkout master
bower jquery#1.7.2                            checkout 1.7.2
bower backbone#1.1.2                          checkout 1.1.2
bower hoverIntent#*                           checkout master
bower handlebars#1.0.0                        checkout 1.0.0
bower requirejs-plugins#1.0.2                 checkout 1.0.2
bower fastclick#1.0.2                         checkout v1.0.2
bower underscore#1.5.1                        checkout 1.5.1
bower supersized-with-swipe#*                 checkout master
bower require-handlebars-plugin#0.8.0          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone http://repository_url/js-ext-libs/require-handlebars-plugin.git -b v0.8.0 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
Cloning into '.'...
fatal: dumb http transport does not support --depth
```

Running bower install again, I got the same result on different packages. I'm the only one about my colleagues with this issue, configurations look very similar.
any clue? I've the following configuration:

```
$ git config --global --list
user.name=myname
user.email=myemail
core.autocrlf=true
credential.helper=!'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\GitCredStore\git-credential-winstore.exe'
http.sslcainfo=c:/Users/myname/Documents/projects/credentials/cert.pem
http.sslverify=false
branch.autosetuprebase=always
url.https://.insteadof=git://
```

Thanks

Comment: What git version are you using? Is this a private bower registry?

Comment: the git version is 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0, I'm on windows and yes, it's a private repository we use to retrieve artifacts using bower
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bower supports dumb http repositories since version 1.3.0

Details about the problem and the implemented solution extracted from https://github.com/bower/bower/pull/1062:

Bower versions <1.3.0 do not support dumb http servers, the solution was to extend the already a mechanism in place to support a fallback to not use depth, to cover this case too.